# How to Set Environment variable on window 10

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I installed fresh Window 10, Now I want to Edit the Environment variable

The first issue I am facing is When I open the Environment variable there is no **PATH** variable in the User variables List you can see in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOR0F.png)

The second issue I faced is When I clicked on Edit for any variable it Open Edit user variable [UnExpectedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXmW3.png) Instead of Edit environment Variable [ExpectedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFtt7.png)

Need guidance how to add **Path variable** now and how to **Edit** it properly

Comment: That is all how it is supposed to work ...

Comment: @DavidPostill but it's not working with me I attached images also

Comment: Did you highlight Path in the second section and edit that?

Comment: Or click new in the first image and add a user path?

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok that is done But the second issue is still I am facing

Comment: "I installed fresh Window 10"   <-- Something may have gone wrong. You can run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link and Keep Everything.  That should correct the error. Editing Path is working fine here on my own machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just specify the variable name PATH in the user vars, and separate the values by semicolons `;` and it should pick it up after you restart the computer. If it doesn't, you can try to [restore the path variable](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/recover-path-environment-variables-on-windows-10/) the proper way.

The reason you're seeing the unexpected dialog is because the original/official PATH var was deleted and Windows just things you're adding adding a custom variable. Go ahead and add several directories to the PATH var and restart. It *should* detect it and act as expected, but.... If you just installed Windows fresh, I recommend reinstalling again because if the PATH var is mising, who knows what else may be wrong.